type I error in multiple comparisons summary statistics
I understand type I error can increase if we run 'multiple comparisons'. But does that refer to comparisons within a multi-category variable (or a group variable)? or multiple analyses using the same variables? In the descriptive statistics, we usually run a univariate test for each predictor vs the outcome. Does that consider as multiple comparisons? Do we need to do something to control the type I error?
say there are two continuous outcomes, one predictor is color with 3 categories (red, blue, green). if we want to do pairwise comparison within color vs outcome0. it's a multiple comparison within one predictor. if we want to compare color vs outcome0, gender vs outcome0, gender vs outcome1, no group is left out. color and gender are independent. do we need to control the type i error?
or if age, gender, color all have 2 groups. I run a t-test for gender vs outcome among age=0, gender vs outcome among age=1, color vs outcome among age=gender=0... I should adjust for type i error correct?
Thanks

To get a nuanced answer, you really need to give more context about what data you are collecting and what questions you are trying to answer with statistical analysis.

In short, a correction for multiple comparisons should be made if there are multiple statistical hypotheses testing the same theoretical claim. So if you are interested in depression, say, and you have three depression scores, and you are willing to say something is associated (or whatever your test is about) with depression if at least one of them comes out significant, you inflate your overall type 1 error without a correction. So it is more about your intention of making claims than about variable types.
I think in your example you might rather want to watch out for the table 2 fallacy:
https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/23371353/

I think what you're referring to as variable is called group in a "more-statistical" lingo.
Type-I error is expected to inflate if we repeatedly compare multiple groups independently (classical example being running 3 separate two-sample t-tests on 3 groups to compare each possible pair instead of ANOVA). It doesn't matter if these variables are nested (subgroups) or not because every time you run the test on a pair, you ignore the left-out group.
Coming to Univariate analyses before fitting a regression model, since the intent of this exercise is purely descriptive you need not worry about controlling Type-I error, because you're not doing any inference.
Hope this helps!

say the outcome is continuous, one predictor is color with 3 categories (red, blue, green). if we want to do pairwise comparison within color vs outcome. it's a multiple comparison within one predictor. if we want to compare color vs outcome, gender vs outcome, no group is left out. color and gender are independent. do we need to control the type i error? or if age, gender, color all have 2 groups. I run a t-test for gender vs outcome among age=0, gender vs outcome among age=1, color vs outcome among age=gender=0... I should adjust for type i error correct?

I suggest you test for interaction first if you have collected data on color and age together. Only then you can call these variables independent of each other with some statistical credibility. If they are independent, I can't think of a reason why you'd have to worry about Type-I error if testing separately.
